# vuejs listing for events on disabled elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How can I listen for events on a disabled element? I have an input box that I have disabled but that I want to enable if the user double clicks it. I know this is possible using a label and switching the label off using CSS. I want to know if there is a way to do this without a label - is there some way to disable the input and still handle events for it? or is there a way to make the input unfocusable unless double-clicked?

Comment: You can add an event listener to the parent element of input if the parent is not bigger than the input.

Comment: You can add a `@click` on the input and then use a timeout to simulate double-click. If there is an aditional click before the timeout is done, you do the logic you want, else, prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the default action of the input with a timeout. If a user clicks before the ms has elapsed, you run the desired code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: false,
    timeoutId: null, // You do not need to have this defined, vue will initialize it for you, but here for clarity
  },
  methods: {
    dblClick(event) {
      // Simple click
      if (!this.timeoutId) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
          this.timeoutId = null;
        }, 300);

        return // Do not run below code if it is a single click
      }

      // double click
      this.timeoutId = null;
      console.log('dblClick')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

i {
  font-size: .75em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #969696;
}

input {
  transform: scale(2);
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Checkbox is {{ checked ? 'checked' : 'not checked' }}</h1>
  <i>Double-click to change</i>
  <input v-model="checked" type="checkbox" @click="dblClick">
</div>
```